# Need regex for project name with the following conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Need regex for the "Project name" with following condition.
Expected Result: Take alphabetical, alpha numeric, alpha numeric symbolic
Actual Result:

```
1.    Take alpha – Pass
2.    Take Numeric – Pass
3.    Take Alpha numeric – Pass
4.    Take alpha numeric special characters - Pass
5.    If Only special characters – Fail
```

that is, Everything is allowed but if it is just special characters and no text than it's a problem.
**Example:

- **zjna5726$7&^#bsg //allowed**
- **%&*% // just special characters not allowed**
- I tried /**^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$**/ but did not help
- ^([\w+\d+*]+)((-)([\w+\d+*]+))* //did not help it is only excepting one character in between only.

Comment: what have you tried? In your probably many attempts, what worked/didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(?=[\W_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\W_]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+).+$` - This regex should fulfil your requirement.

```
alpha="abc"
numeric="123456789"
alphaNumeric="Abc1234"
alphaNumericSpcl="#Abc1234$!@~!"
onlySpcl="!@#$%^&*()_-+={}\|][:;'\".,><?/`"
randomString="!@#$%^&*()_-abde9+={}\|][:;'\".,><?/`"

regex=/^(?=[\W_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\W_]|[a-zA-Z0-9]+).+$/
console.log("Test of Alpha:",regex.test(alpha));
console.log("Test of Numeric:",regex.test(numeric));
console.log("Test of Alphanumeric:",regex.test(alphaNumeric));
console.log("Test of Alphanumeric and Special:",regex.test(alphaNumericSpcl));
console.log("Test of only Special:",regex.test(onlySpcl));
console.log("Test of Random String:",regex.test(randomString));
```

Output:

```
Test of Alpha: true
Test of Numeric: true
Test of Alphanumeric: true
Test of Alphanumeric and Special: true
Test of only Special: false
Test of Random String: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check if there is included Numeric or Alpha?

```
if("string".match(/A-Za-z0-9/)) // do something
else // do something else
```

Comment: Well, at present I have done it like that only but I wondered if it can done through regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is not just simply to check that this has a match ? /\w+/

if (teststring.match(/\w+/) != null)
..